# MeteorJS MongoDB Deploy Error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

For some reason when I use Meteor deploy my server produces the following error and I am unable to access the pages. I'm running into the following error:

> WARNING Error: No replica set primary available for query with
>   ReadPreference PRIMARY

I am using Meteor 1.1.0.2 and run meteor deploy x.meteor.com. The logs are then queried via meteor logs x.meteor.com. It was working up until recently.

Any help would be appreciated, the full meteor log output is below.

> [Tue May 05 2015 20:50:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING
>   /meteor/dev_bundles/0.4.18/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
>   throw(ex); [Tue May 05 2015 20:50:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING
>   ^ [Tue May 05 2015 20:50:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: No replica
>   set primary available for query with ReadPreference PRIMARY at
>   Object.Future.wait
>   (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.4.18/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:395:16)
>   at [object Object].MongoConnection._ensureIndex
>   (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:733:1) at [object
>   Object].Mongo.Collection._ensureIndex
>   (packages/mongo/collection.js:620:1) at Accounts.urls
>   (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1309:1) at
>   /meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1616:4
>   at
>   /meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1659:3
>   at
>   /meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
>   at Array.forEach (native) at Function.*.each.*.forEach
>   (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.4.18/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>   at
>   /meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
>   at [object Object].ReplSet.checkoutReader
>   (/meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/repl_set/repl_set.js:613:14)
>   at Cursor.nextObject
>   (/meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:748:48)
>   at Cursor.toArray
>   (/meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:10)
>   at Db.indexInformation
>   (/meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1629:39)
>   at Db.ensureIndex
>   (/meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1496:8)
>   at Collection.ensureIndex
>   (/meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/index.js:68:11)
>   at [object Object].MongoConnection._ensureIndex
>   (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:732:1) at [object
>   Object].Mongo.Collection._ensureIndex
>   (packages/mongo/collection.js:620:1) at Accounts.urls
>   (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1309:1) at
>   /meteor/containers/93192c1f-5c41-157d-36a5-dceb494f7e2c/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1616:4
>   [Tue May 05 2015 20:50:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running ->
>   starting [Tue May 05 2015 20:50:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application
>   crashed with code: 8 [Tue May 05 2015 20:50:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE
>   Starting application on port 23497 [Tue May 05 2015 20:50:15 GMT+0000
>   (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: This generally indicates an issue with the MongoDB and the driver being unable to connect.

Right at this very moment is seems numerous people are having this problem with their *.meteor.com applications. I would wait a bit and then try to redeploy.

Comment: The servers were down for a bit. That's probably what was wrong.